# Financial instruments ranking based on price movement (outliers, consistency)

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, mean, ranking, measurement

I have a lot of financial instruments and I need to rank them based on price movement "stability", i.e. instruments with with big outliers should have the lowest ranks and instruments with stable and consistent moves should have the highest ranks. To solve this issue I use the ratio of the `Arithmetic Mean` to the `Standard Deviation` for every instrument and then sort them by this ratio. But there is a problem: this method works only roughly and some "bad" instruments have higher ranks than "good" instruments.

Are there are different approaches for ranking?

For data points I use $\ln(\text{High} / \text{Low})$ and period is 750 data points for every instrument.

Comment: In what sense have some "bad" instruments outperformed "good" ones on this measure? That implies there is some independent way to determine instrument quality. If you have such a way, why are you not using that way instead?

Comment: Just with my eyes. For example one instrument can have one very large outlier, second instrument can have more outliers but less large. For me second instrument is better.